# SDL save screenshot on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, sdl, sdl-image

I am trying to save a screen or frame from the SDL's "window" into a PNG file and so I'm using [SDL_image library](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/). My code is below

```
IMG_Init(Int32(IMG_INIT_PNG.rawValue))
let screenShot = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 640, 480, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0)
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture)
SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, nil, Uint32(SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888), screenShot?.pointee.pixels, (screenShot?.pointee.pitch)!)
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
IMG_SavePNG(screenShot, "\(documentsPath)/image.png")
SDL_FreeSurface(screenShot)
```

But the `image.png` was not saved. If anyone can lead or help me. Thank you!

Additional code, the image saved is just black

```
IMG_Init(Int32(IMG_INIT_PNG.rawValue))
let screenShot = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(Uint32(SDL_SWSURFACE), 640, 480, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0)
// SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture)
SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, nil, Uint32(SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888), screenShot?.pointee.pixels, (screenShot?.pointee.pitch)!)
// Save to documents directory
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("imageLOL.png")
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path) {
        print("File NO exists")
        // Create file at path
        let data = Data()
        let createFile = fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileUrl.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        if createFile {
            print("Create file success")
        } else {
            print("Create file failed")
        }
    } else {
        print("File exists")

    }
    let result = IMG_SavePNG(screenShot, fileUrl.path)
    print("result = \(result)")
    // After saving screenshot
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileUrl.path)
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
    print("image length = \(String(describing: imageData?.count))")
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
    SDL_FreeSurface(screenShot)
} catch {
    print("Error docs = \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? Can you save any file with that path? What does `SDL_GetError()` returns after failed save?

Comment: Based on the documentation you can also save as "image.png" without the file path. But I can't seem to find the image. Is it supposed to be saved somewhere?

Comment: @keltar the SDL_GetError() returns 0x00000001032b60c0

Comment: And the parameter with just the "image.png" returns 0x00000001030c20c0

Comment: `SDL_GetError` returns `const char*`, which is a text string. Address makes no sense for me, as it may change on each run, sorry. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018494/converting-from-const-char-to-swift-string

Comment: @keltar the message is ERROR: NumPoints = 0 does it make sense?

Comment: are you sure you are using the version 2.0 of the library not v1.2

Comment: @abhishek it is now working, I just created the directory and the file first before calling that method. But now the saved file is just black. I'm not sure why

Comment: are you trying to capture the screenshot of a video while it is giving you black image?

Comment: @abhishek I am trying to capture a screenshot of a video while it is playing and it is not black. It is a cartoon video

Comment: Please have a look at my answer for this

Comment: @abhishek edited my question with additional code

Comment: have you tried to take screenshot of your app's screen except video playback. Please try once and let me know if it is working for you

Comment: @abhishek Tried taking screenshot of my screen and yes it is displaying the view of my ViewController

Comment: Could yo show a MCVE? Also saving the image as "image.png", without path will put it where your application is installed and AFAIK you can't access this outside of the application itself (sans jailbreak).

Comment: at least upvote or accept my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Have you tried passing in 0 into the pixel format paramater of `SDL_RenderReadPixels` ? Docs say this will make it use the same format as the Rendering target. which could be your issue with the all black pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to save the screenshot from the SDL_window. First I create a PNG representation file like

```
let image = UIImage()
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
try data?.write(to: fileUrl)
```

then after that you call IMG_SavePNG() method

Comment: @abhishek yes I have, the thing is I need to create a directory and file before IMG_SavePNG can save the image

Answer (score 2):

It will not give you the video frame in the screenshot. It will give you black screen image only when you are playing the video.

Please try to take the screenshot of any of your app's screen and see if it is working.